# Pandas dataframe: Fill in interpolated date values per category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data, linear-interpolation

I'm working in Python 3 with a Pandas DataFrame. It has columns for Category, Date and Value. For each category, I want to add rows with the missing days, such the value is linearly interpolated.

To create the minimal example, I use the following code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'cat':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
'date': ['2021-1-1', '2021-1-4', '2021-1-5', '2021-1-7', '2021-11-1', '2021-11-2', '2021-11-5'],
'value': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 9.0]})

df['cat'] = df['cat'].astype('category')
df['date'] = df['date'].astype('datetime64')
```

Which gives the following dataframe

```
cat date          value
A   2021-01-01    1.0
A   2021-01-04    2.0
A   2021-01-05    3.0
A   2021-01-07    4.0
B   2021-11-01    5.0
B   2021-11-02    6.0
B   2021-11-05    9.0
```

I would like the output to be like this example, Where I used '<' to indicate the newly inserted rows

```
cat date          value
A   2021-01-01    1.0
A   2021-01-02    1.333  <
A   2021-01-03    1.667  <
A   2021-01-04    2.0
A   2021-01-05    3.0
A   2021-01-06    3.5    <
A   2021-01-07    4.0
B   2021-11-01    5.0
B   2021-11-02    6.0
B   2021-11-03    7.0    <
B   2021-11-04    8.0    <
B   2021-11-05    9.0
```

In the actual problem, I don't want the weekend-days (Saturdays and Sundays), but I've stated the problem like above to prevent adding extra layers (I can easily filter the weekend-days out later if needed). However, not including them in the first place may allow for more efficient code, so I'd thought I'd mention this snag as well. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with resample or [`Series.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html) for missing values for days and then interpolate per groups in lambda function:

```
df = (df.set_index('date')
        .groupby('cat')['value']
        .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('d').interpolate())
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   cat       date     value
0    A 2021-01-01  1.000000
1    A 2021-01-02  1.333333
2    A 2021-01-03  1.666667
3    A 2021-01-04  2.000000
4    A 2021-01-05  3.000000
5    A 2021-01-06  3.500000
6    A 2021-01-07  4.000000
7    B 2021-11-01  5.000000
8    B 2021-11-02  6.000000
9    B 2021-11-03  7.000000
10   B 2021-11-04  8.000000
11   B 2021-11-05  9.000000
```

---

```
df = (df.set_index('date')
        .groupby('cat')['value']
        .apply(lambda x: x.resample('d').first().interpolate())
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   cat       date     value
0    A 2021-01-01  1.000000
1    A 2021-01-02  1.333333
2    A 2021-01-03  1.666667
3    A 2021-01-04  2.000000
4    A 2021-01-05  3.000000
5    A 2021-01-06  3.500000
6    A 2021-01-07  4.000000
7    B 2021-11-01  5.000000
8    B 2021-11-02  6.000000
9    B 2021-11-03  7.000000
10   B 2021-11-04  8.000000
11   B 2021-11-05  9.000000
```

Or:

```
f = lambda x: x.interpolate()
s = df.set_index('date').groupby('cat')['value'].resample('d').first().groupby(level=0).apply(f)
print (s)
cat  date      
A    2021-01-01    1.000000
     2021-01-02    1.333333
     2021-01-03    1.666667
     2021-01-04    2.000000
     2021-01-05    3.000000
     2021-01-06    3.500000
     2021-01-07    4.000000
B    2021-11-01    5.000000
     2021-11-02    6.000000
     2021-11-03    7.000000
     2021-11-04    8.000000
     2021-11-05    9.000000
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Also helped me learn about the way to think about these type of problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a helper function:

```
def interpolate(d, on='date', vals=['value']):
    return (d.set_index(on).reindex(pd.date_range(d[on].min(), d[on].max()))
             [vals].interpolate()
             .rename_axis(on)
           ) 

df.groupby('cat').apply(interpolate).reset_index()
```

output:

```
   cat       date     value
0    A 2021-01-01  1.000000
1    A 2021-01-02  1.333333
2    A 2021-01-03  1.666667
3    A 2021-01-04  2.000000
4    A 2021-01-05  3.000000
5    A 2021-01-06  3.500000
6    A 2021-01-07  4.000000
7    B 2021-11-01  5.000000
8    B 2021-11-02  6.000000
9    B 2021-11-03  7.000000
10   B 2021-11-04  8.000000
11   B 2021-11-05  9.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is a combination of [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) with [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete):

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor

dates = dict(date = lambda df: pd.date_range(df.min(), df.max(), freq='1D'))

(df.complete(dates, by='cat', sort = True)
   .assign(value = lambda df: df.value.interpolate())
)
   cat       date     value
0    A 2021-01-01  1.000000
1    A 2021-01-02  1.333333
2    A 2021-01-03  1.666667
3    A 2021-01-04  2.000000
4    A 2021-01-05  3.000000
5    A 2021-01-06  3.500000
6    A 2021-01-07  4.000000
7    B 2021-11-01  5.000000
8    B 2021-11-02  6.000000
9    B 2021-11-03  7.000000
10   B 2021-11-04  8.000000
11   B 2021-11-05  9.000000
```

`complete` exposes the missing values,after which we then interpolate on a `linear` method.

Comment: :D I really thought "*now it's only missing the pyjanitor solution, where is sammywemmy?*". Well, here you are ;)